# Build Insert Statement using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spread sheet with content as below.

```
EMPLOYEE_ID ATT_DATE    ATT_TIME
1           10/9/2012   10:47:00
1           10/9/2012   10:47:00
1           10/9/2012   10:48:00
1           10/9/2012   10:49:00
1           10/9/2012   10:55:00
```

I want to create insert statements from these values. so i wrote below formula to generate insert statements.

```
="INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (EMPLOYEE_ID, ATT_DATE) VALUES('" & Attendance!A2 & "', to_date('" & TEXT(Attendance!B2,"dd-mmm-yyyy") & "','DD-MON-YYYY'));"
```

i want to add values in `ATT_TIME` column to above insert statements. but i'm unable to write formula correctly for that.

how could i add values in `ATT_TIME` column to my insert statements ?

PS: i'm using oracle database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `to_date('" & Attendance!C2 & "','HH24:MI:SS')`  ?

Here is the complete query

```
="INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (EMPLOYEE_ID, ATT_DATE, ATT_TIME) VALUES('" & Attendance!A2 & "', to_date('" & TEXT(Attendance!B2,"dd-mmm-yyyy") & "','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('" & Attendance!C2 & "','HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Answer (score 1):

i have found solution for my question.

```
="INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (EMPLOYEE_ID, ATT_DATE, ATT_TIME) VALUES('"&Attendance!A2&"', to_date('"&TEXT(Attendance!B2,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&"','DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('"&TEXT(Attendance!C2,"h:mm:ss")&"','HH24:MI:SS'));"
```